# Adding an iterator of a trait on another trait

Tags: rust

I have a trait which has a function that should return an iterator of a different trait. I also need a common function which takes this trait and does operations on it.

This is the code I have currenty:

```
pub trait NodeLike : Sized {
    /// Get the node id
    fn get_id(&self) -> i32;
}

pub trait EdgeLike {
    /// Get the destination node id
    fn get_node_id(&self) -> i32;

    /// Get the edge id
    fn get_edge_id(&self) -> i32;

    /// iterates of the source nodes
    fn iter_source_nodes(&self) -> dyn Iterator<Item = dyn NodeLike>;
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

fn operation(id: i32, edge: dyn EdgeLike) {
    for node in edge.iter_source_nodes().find(|n| n.get_id() == id) {
        
    }
}
```

The underlined part above throws the compiler error:

```
the trait `NodeLike` cannot be made into an object
`NodeLike` cannot be made into an object rustc E0038
main.rs(1, 22): for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
```

Reading through the documentation, I believe my `NodeLike` trait is object-safe. The only function it has is `&Self (i.e. &self)`

Now, I can further my code by removing the `Sized` trait on `NodeLike`. However, then the error occurs in the function `operation`; I cannot use the `find` function on the iterator.

How can I change my code so that I can make `NodeLike` object safe, AND be able to return an iterator which I can call `find` on?

Comment: You should probably box it `Item= Box<dyn NodeLike>`

Comment: Tried that, still the same problem

Comment: better: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a97fdceaa58aef3a5a467b6987d1eab0

Comment: @Stargateur thanks, that got me past the compiler for the traits, but the problem seems to be just moved to the implementation: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3cf0cdd6a6916b65cd81cbbc44ca15a4

Comment: stop use dyn keyword, stop, stop, no, don't, stop, I will watch you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Stargateur's suggestion and your playground link, I got it to compile like this:

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b2bd9a7490b24029a7f348876aa135a6)

This is if you do not want to use any unstable features.

The trick is to specify the explicit type of the iterator. If you don't know that type, just put any stupid type in and let the compiler complain about the type mismatch. It'll tell you that we're dealing here with a slice iter, so hence the `std::slice::Iter`.

The other modifications are then about adding a lifetime parameter to your struct, because `iter()` returns references. If you don't want that, change it to `into_iter`, but then you must use `self` instead of `&self`.

Also, for your operation, you must do some lifetime magic...

```rust
fn operation<'a, Item: NodeLike>(id: i32, edge: &'a impl EdgeLike<'a, Item=Item> )
```

If you are okay with unstable features, you can avoid having to specify the *exact* type of the iter: In *your* playground version just change the `dyn` to `impl`. The compiler will tell you that that's an unstable feature and will show you the macro to use.

Finally, to avoid having to add lifetime annotations to the trait itself, there's something about generic associated types, but maybe that's going too far for now.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I was able to get this to work using unstable features as you suggested.

Comment: Just FYI for anyone who runs into this issue, after following all of this answer, when I actually try to call the `operation` function, the compiler still complained that `&Node` does not satisfy the `NodeLike` trait. I have to add an implementation of `NodeLike` for `&Node` AND `Node`. Here's the final working version: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3e9bf978b05da03fcd99b86a811f2dcd